# How to fix this syntax error?

Tags: syntax-error

this is my log in code. i am working on my dbms project. i have removed all the errors, as error list is showing 0 errors but when i m executing this, i m having this error at the top of my web page that **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.** and on remaining page there is my log in form appearing. i don't know how to fix this all. please let me know ASAP.
here is the code of log in form page.
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        try
        {
            //making necessary connections for linking database

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=BUSHRA-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=fb;Integrated Security=True");

        conn.Open(); // openning connection
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from user where Userid='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", conn);
        //cmd.Connection = conn;
        SqlDataReader dr = null;
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            TextBox1.Text = dr["Userid"].ToString();
        }
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Application["Userid"] = dr[0].ToString();
            Application["Password"] = dr[1].ToString();
            Application["Rollid"] = dr[2].ToString();

            if (dr[0].ToString() == TextBox1.Text && dr[1].ToString() == TextBox3.Text)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt16(dr[2].ToString()) == 2)
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");
                    }


                else if (Convert.ToInt16((dr[2])) == 1)

                    {
                        Response.Redirect("StudentFB.aspx");
                    }

                }   
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message); // if try fails display the error

    }
```

Comment: This may well be a [tag:syntax-error], but what *language* is it, consider adding that to your tags.

Comment: What's the value of TextBox1.Text is there any single quote?

Comment: Slap on the wrist for using TextBox1.Text in your SQL. You are prone to SQL Injection attacks. You should fix that. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Slap on the wrist for only one user being able to log in to the site at a time (`Application`) is a variable whose scope is common to all users.

Answer (score 2):

`user` is a reserved keyword. Quote it, either with double quotes `"user"`, or brackets `[user]`.